15" MacBook Pro 2018 stopped charging after installing AlDente power management software
I installed the app AlDente and used it for some time. When I changed the limiter to 80%, it stopped charging at 80% as expected. After some time the macbook stopped charging. I uninstalled the app, according to the steps mentioned on their website but it still didn't charge. Now the battery is at zero charge and the MacBook won't start. I can't do anything. What should I do?

Try this https://support.apple.com/en-gu/102605

Have you tested with another charger?  Does the LED turn on when you plug the charger into the laptop?

I would take it to an Apple Store, or other Apple-authorised repair shop. A 6-year-old battery will likely need changing.

@benwiggy I have a very very old macbook with a battery that is totally shot. It still charges up to 100% very quickly and from 100% to 0 in less than ten minutes, but the Mac is not dead.

@gnasher729 Well, that's one data point for the graph of all battery data! ;-) Some batteries go on minimally for years. Some fail completely.
